# Validation of Html 5 Datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Html5 date picker in my project of room reservation system please anybody help me to validate this date picker. Validation must include disabling dates earlier than today's date disabling dates which have been selected earlier for rooms.

```html
    <html>
<body>
<form name="f2" action="payment.jsp" method="get" >
            <label> Date:</label><br>
            From:<input type="date" name="from" id="myDate" value="demo">
            Till:<input type="date" name="till" id="myDate1" value="demo1"><br>
  
 <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
     var y = document.getElementById("myDate1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
}      
</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: shouldn't `demo` and `demo1` values be actual dates? like 2016-10-17?

Comment: also, take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574442/how-to-add-validation-restrictions-for-html5-date-field-without-jquery-javascrip. It has some tips you can use

Comment: It has been already discussed in stack.Please [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335120/jquery-validator-and-datepicker-click-not-validating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript to validate date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344015/javascript-to-validate-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JS to accomplish that: There is  attr `min` on html5:

```
<input type="date" name="from" id="myDate" value="demo" min="2016-10-13">
```

To update it to the current date, I use `todayDate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDate').attr('min', todayDate());
});
```

```js
function todayDate() {
    var today = new Date(); // get the current date
    var dd = today.getDate(); //get the day from today.
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //get the month from today +1 because january is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); //get the year from today

    //if day is below 10, add a zero before (ex: 9 -> 09)
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    }

    //like the day, do the same to month (3->03)
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    }

    //finally join yyyy mm and dd with a "-" between then
    return yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDate').attr('min', todayDate());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form name="f2" action="payment.jsp" method="get" >
            <label> Date:</label><br>
            From:<input type="date" name="from" id="myDate" value="demo" min="2016-10-13">
            Till:<input type="date" name="till" id="myDate1" value="demo1"><br>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sandrina thanks alot .. please help me out to set min attribute as todays date which changes each day...

Comment: thanks a lot sandrina for your valuable help.. I just copied your snippet and it worked for me as i am a fresher i am new to ajax , javascript  so its difficult for me to understand it.

Comment: look again to my answer. i tried to explain what's going on inside the function :)

Comment: Hope to learn a lot of things in future ma'am. Owned huge respect..@Sandrina

Comment: Thank you :) I believe that sharing knowledge is what make us better every day.